# How to set Authorization Token in RTK Query

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

How do I set Authorization token? This is what I tried to do but I still get an error 401. I'm new to RTK Query.............

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const customersApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "customersApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000' }),
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
        const token = getState().auth.user.token;
    
        // If we have a token set in state, let's assume that we should be passing it.
        if (token) {
          headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
        }
    
        return headers
      },
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        customers: builder.query({
            query: () =>'/api/v1/customer/paginate-customer',
        })
    })
})

export const {
    useCustomersQuery
} = customersApi
```

Comment: And do you see the token get sent to the server when you look at the request in your browser's "network" tab?

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead

```
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: BASE_URL,
->  headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`},
  }),
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that retrieves the token from localStorage or from the location where it is stored. The function should look like this:

```
export const getTokenFromLocalStorage = () => {
    return localStorage.getItem('X_auth_token');
};


Import the function in your component and call the endpoint like this:
import {getTokenFromLocalStorage} from './utility'
getUsers: builder.query({
    query: (params = {}) => ({
        url: '/user',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${getTokenFromLocalStorage()}`,
        },
    }),
}),
```

Comment: i get the error 

    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'headers' does not exist in type 'Omit<EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<string,